# Concatenate arrays in an array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, concatenation, reduce

I currently have a field in MongoDB that is a list of arrays. I would like to convert all this into a string, but I first need (I guess?) to concatenate my list of arrays into one single array before converting it.

Here is what my field looks like :

```
"SitesList" : [
        [
            "553550", 
            "496573", 
            "496574"
        ], 
        [
            "553550", 
            "496573", 
            "496574"
        ], 
        [
            "527772", 
            "565085"
        ], 
        [
            "565085", 
            "563248"
        ], 
        [
            "496576"
        ]
    ]
```

Here's what I tried so far to concatenate it (with `concatArrays`), but it's not working:

```
{ $addFields: {"Sites": { $concatArrays: ["$tdb.Data.site.list"]}}},
```

And what I would like to do ultimately to convert the final array into a string:

```
SitesList: {
                            $reduce: {
                                input: "$Sites",
                                initialValue: "",
                                in: {$concat: ["$$value",",",  {$toString:"$$this"}]}
                            }
                    },
```

Can someone one help me please? :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Begs the question: why make MongoDB do this?  You're not filtering or aggregating.  Why not simply fetch `SitesList` and format as desired on the client side?

Comment: Hi @BuzzMoschetti, actually, I need to export my MongoDB data and insert it into an SQL Server database. That's why I want to get rid of arrays :)
This is also not my full query which is much longer and complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try,

- `$reduce` to get concat arrays in single array and other `$reduce` to convert array to string using `$concat` and [$substr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/index.html) to remove extra `,` from beginning of the string,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      SitesList: {
        $substr: [
          {
            $reduce: {
              input: {
                $reduce: {
                  input: "$SitesList",
                  initialValue: [],
                  in: { $concatArrays: ["$$this", "$$value"] }
                }
              },
              initialValue: "",
              in: { $concat: ["$$value", ",", "$$this"] }
            }
          },
          1,
          -1
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RJOYCR5JeGV)