# Concatenate Array in Mongodb in One Line

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework, concatenation, reduce

I'm trying to convert array to one line statement. It has MainArray and SubArray.

Here's the Table Looks Like:

Table Name: MainArray.SubArray

| Column 0 | Column 1 |
| --- | --- |
| Cell R | Cell U |
| Cell C | Cell D |

Output:

"Test" : R , U
"Test" : C , D

I'd tried using the recommended codes [Here in the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64824503/concatenate-arrays-in-an-array-in-mongodb)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmJ27.png)

Here's the sample output I tried coding, I'd like to the column Permission would be single output with the same role code.

Comment: Your output is not a valid JSON/BSON document. Please try to provide these: 1. Sample Input JSON/BSON document 2. Your query to attempt 3. Sample Output JSON/BSON document

Comment: @YongShun hello, I'd edited the inquiry.